# Angular 12 project worker has the error - Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm upgrading a project to Angular 12 and the following code snippet used to work fine

```
    worker.postMessage(csvFile.data)
    worker.onmessage = ({ data }: { data: ParseResult<any> }) => {
```

Now the line `worker.onmessage = ({ data }: { data: ParseResult<any> }` has the error:

```
Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)
(alias) interface ParseResult<T>
import ParseResult
data: is an array of rows. If header is false, rows are arrays; otherwise they are objects of data keyed by the field name. errors: is an array of errors meta: contains extra information about the parse, such as delimiter used, the newline sequence, whether the process was aborted, etc. Properties in this object are not guaranteed to exist in all situations
```

And the project will not compile.  Any ideas?

If I set `tsconfig.json` `noImplicityReturns` to `false` it compiles ... but I was wondering if there's a more "Correct" way to fix this?

Comment: It'd probably help for a specific answer if you posted the complete extract of what you're assigning to `worker.onmessage`. My guess without seeing the latter is that you might have an early `return` with some value without specifying a catch-all `return` at the end.

Comment: @migh You are right.  If a validation check fails, I return.  And if not I just allow the code to complete.  If you want to post that as the answer that would be awesome.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, the suggestion was that the expression being assigned to `worker.onmessage` might have had an early `return` statement with some value, whilst there isn't a catch-all `return` at the conclusion of the expression. This would be sufficient to trigger the TS compiler error which would otherwise be suppressed by `--noImplicitReturns`.